# Join Delete in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

I'm having a hard time converting my sybase script into an Oracle 11g script. I used the translation tool but I got even more confuse with the Rowid.
Is there any easier way to do it without using rowid so it's easier for me, who just learn Oracle, to digest?

**Here is my Sybase script:**

```
delete table_1       
    from table_1 a, table_2 b     
    where (select count(*) from table_2       
                where a.id = id       
                    and a.seq = seq       
                    and a.gcode = gcode       
                    and a.gtype = gtype) = 0       
    and a.id = b.id    
    and a.seq = b.seq;
```

**Here is the result from Oracle SQL development translation tool:**

```
 DELETE table_1
   WHERE ROWID IN 
   ( SELECT a.ROWID
     FROM table_1 a,
          table_2 b
    WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM table_2 
             WHERE a.id = id
                  AND a.seq = seq
                  AND a.gcode = gcode
                  AND a.gtype = gtype ) = 0
         AND a.id = b.id
         AND a.seq = b.seq );
```

**Is it safe to write using ID instead of RowId?:**
IDs in both table_1 and table_2 refer to the same PK. Table_1 and table_2 are mirror of each other.

```
 DELETE table_1
   WHERE ID IN 
   ( SELECT DISTINCT a.ID
     FROM table_1 a,
          table_2 b
    WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM table_2 
             WHERE a.id = id
                  AND a.seq = seq
                  AND a.gcode = gcode
                  AND a.gtype = gtype ) = 0
         AND a.id = b.id
         AND a.seq = b.seq );
```

Answer (score 0):

Rowid identifies a row. Two rows cannot have the same rowid. If the id in your table is the primary key (not part if a composite key) then you basically achieve the same by using id. However rowid is generally provides faster access as it references the physical location of a row and does not have to access the row by using the index.

Answer (score 0):

beware of partitioning. There can be same rowid on different partitions, so the above statement about uniqnuness of rowid is not valid for partitioned tables